# using a string as a command in java

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, jsoup

I have a string named "var" where the text string is set as doc1, doc2 or doc3

```
String var = "doc2" // doc1 or doc2 or doc3
```

I get content from the website using Jsoup this way

```
Document doc_comp = Jsoup.connect("http://www.computer.org").get();            
        Elements doc1_comp  = doc_comp.select("ul > doc1" );                                
        Elements doc2_comp  = doc_comp.select("ul > doc2" );
        Elements doc3_comp  = doc_comp.select("ul > doc3" );
```

I use switch case for the corresponding values to be printed

```
       switch(var)
        {
        case "doc1": System.out.println(doc1_comp.text());
        break;
        case "doc2":System.out.println(doc2_comp.text());
        break;
        case "doc3":System.out.println(doc3_comp.text());
        break;
        default: System.out.println("no info");
        }
```

Everything works perfectly fine with the switch case but I want to use a single line of code to replace switch case like this

```
System.out.println(var.concat("_comp.text()"));
```

but it straight away prints as a string **"var_comp.text()"** but does not execute it and print the content inside it.

Is there a way around to make it run

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I need the HTML text content of doc1_comp to be printed.

Comment: @user1364432 So basically, you have a string that contains the text of a method call (in this case, `"docX_comp.text()"` where X is a number), and you want to execute that method rather than just printing out the string?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to execute the method.

Comment: @user1364432 so instead of switch you want to execute it with only one line of code?

Comment: yup! thats right.  1 line of code to replace the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Ternary operator` which will replace the `switch statement` into one line of code, but using ternary operator doesn't make it faster or efficient than switch statement.

**sample:**

```
System.out.println(var.equals("doc1") ? doc1_comp.text() : (var.equals("doc2") ? doc2_comp.text() : ( var.equals("doc3") ? doc3_comp.text() : "no info" ) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `switch` statement is good(in fact `best option`). But if you really want to execute string contents,
you can achieve it by using a lightweight scripting framework like `java script` or `bean shell`.

> I will discourage it over something which can be achieved with in java,
>   but there certainly are some cases where using scripting frameworks
>   as glue is really required.

see below example using javascript:

```
package com.demo.test;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class ScriptTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine jse = new ScriptEngineManager()
                .getEngineByName("javascript");
        Bindings bindings = jse.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        ScriptTest test = new ScriptTest();
        bindings.put("test", test);
        String preFix = "demo";
        jse.eval("test." + preFix + "_test()");
        preFix = "actual";
        jse.eval("test." + preFix + "_test()");
    }

    public void demo_test() {
        System.out.println("demo test");
    }

    public void actual_test() {
        System.out.println("actual test");
    }
}
```

> This certainly is not a single line solution as it needs the script
>   environment to be set. Also you need to take care of object passing in two contexts

`Note:` this will affect the performance `severely`. (execution namespace switching is costly)
personally I prefer beanshell over javascript, its performance is a bit better but then you need to include its dependent jars (although small footprint) which is not the case with javascript which runs  out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `var` directly in your `doc_comp.select()` method and in your `System.out.println()` method. For example:

```
String var = "doc2" // doc1 or doc2 or doc3
Document doc_comp = Jsoup.connect("http://www.computer.org").get();            
Elements doc_comp_var  = doc_comp.select("ul > " + var);
System.out.println(doc_comp_var.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use reflection, but that isn't very performant, usually adds complexity and makes code less safe.

I might be misunderstanding *exactly* what you're trying to achieve, but I think it'd be simplest to put all those document `Elements` into a `HashMap<String, Elements>`. It wouldn't make a one-liner, but it'd perform better than Reflection, and makes the code more concise. Like so:

```
Document doc_comp = Jsoup.connect("http://www.computer.org").get(); 

Map<String, Elements> map = new HashMap<>();

for(int i=1; i < 4; ++i) {
    map.put("doc" +i+ "_comp", doc_comp.select("ul > doc"+i) );                                
}
```

and then:

```
Elements elem = map.get(var + "_comp");
if( elem != null ) {
    System.out.println( elem.text() );
}
else {
    System.out.println("no info");
}
```

---

*In general*, if you want to "dispatch" certain methods based on `Strings` and want to avoid reflection, then a reasonable approach is to design an `interface`, put class instances that implement that interface into a `Map`, and perform map look-ups to perform the dispatching.

*ie.*

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class A implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("do something class A");
    }        
}

public class B implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("do something class B");
    }
}
```

You then create a "dispatch map" (possibly during application start up):

```
Map<String, MyInterface> dispatchMap = new HashMap<>();
dispatchMap.put("thingA", new A());
dispatchMap.put("thingB", new B());
dispatchMap.put("thingX", new A()); // etc...
```

And have a method that uses the dispatch map to look-up the code to execute:

```
public void doSomethingBasedOnString(String thingName) {

    MyInterface code = dispatchMap.get(thingName);

    if( code != null ) {
        code.doSomething();
    }
    else {
        // dynamic code lookup failed
    }
}
```

Later client code can dynamically execute methods using your dispatch mechanism:

```
doSomethingBasedOnString("thingB");    // outputs: "do something class B"
```